# What is the best stategy to update modules version in multi-module Maven project

Tags: java, maven, version, multi-module

Given: multi-module Maven project

Task: update version after every release

I see 2 different strategies:

**strategy 1** - *throughout update*: update versions of all modules despite the fact were there updates or not

**strategy 2** - *minimalistic update*: update only version of those modules that were actually affected

Assume that we have the following project structure:

```
root
---dao
---domain
---web
   ---site1
   ---site2
---processors
    ---processor1
        ---processor1Service
        ---processor1Util
        ---processor1Tests
    ---processor2
        ---processor2Service
        ---processor2Util
        ---processor2Tests
---simulators
    ---simulator1
        ---simulator1Service
        ---simulator1Util
        ---simulator1Tests
    ---simulator2
        ---simulator2Service
        ---simulator2Util
        ---simulator2Tests
---etc
```

all parent pom has packaging type - pom. All end up modules have resource producing type - jar, war, sar, etc.
Root pom contains *dependencyManagement* section where all child modules are listed.

---

strategy 1:

- release manager RM (or whoever) merges updates from 'feature'
  branch(s)
- all continuous integration stuffs are happening (let them be ok)
- RM calls mvn release:versionUpdate -DsetVersion=1.2 on the root
- done

strategy 2:

- RM merges updates from 'feature' branch(s)
- all continuous integration stuffs are happening (let them be ok)
- RM checks modules that were actually affected using subversion tools (git, svn, whatever)
- RM increments version of affected modules manually
- done

---

**strategy 1:**

*benefits*:

1. no manual input from a human (except version number maybe)
2. pom configuration is trivial and uniformly, can be handled only on root pom using dependencyManagement section
3. a single version of all modules as a result there is no zoo of
   module version
4. no need to depend on external tools that must check where were
   actual updates (or even worse - to depend on a RM attentiveness)
5. developers are not restricted to make any changes not related to
   their module (f.e. no need to afraid if you add new line or
   accidentally run automatic formatting tool in IDE)

disadvantages:

1. will be updated versions of modules that are actually were not
   affected - as a result possible issue with HDD space

**strategy 2:**

*benefits:*

1. will be updated versions of modules that were actually updated

*disadvantages:*

1. zoo of version. dao_1.2 depends on domain_1.52, both depends on
   etc_1.639 module
2. manual input
3. dependence from external tools that must check actual updates

Please share your opinion. How this issue is handled in big projects like e.g. springframework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I will go absolutely for your strategy 1. That's the strategy is used in a company I work for. Your side effect that you mention as HDD space or upgrading module versions which are not required to be upgraded are minor issues compares to "versions zoo".

Only I will vote for your strategy number 2 in cases that you are using OSGI architecture and this requires very precise module versionning strategy, and if you upgrade all the version at once, it will ruin the big benefict of OSGI (hot-deploy only the modules/submodules which require to be updated).

I also suggest you to have a look on http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-i-never-use-maven-release which gives good hints how to upgrade version in multi module maven project, and also how to tracked in any CVS

Comment: thank you for answer. Could you tell me approximately how many modules there are in your project(s), for statistics purpose. Did you try to use strategy 2 and disappointed it it or you use #1 all the time

Comment: Well at work, we are using OSGI arquitecture, so every jar/module exposes their own version because of the OSGI nature.
So whenever a upgrade/fix ocurrs only a deployable jar/module is required to updated not the all project.
But in previous experience in J2EE enviroment, we upgrade all the deployable/jar modules at one.
You should chose a strategy depending in your "deployable-unit".
In OSGI the deployable unit is a jar, so you should go for  a unique version per module. In a J2ee enviroment, because the deployable unit is a war.It doesnt mind to upgrade all the dependencies at one